# How do I fix this Xlint:path error when using Gradle, JUNG and Error Prone?

Tags: java, gradle, jung, errorprone

I am having difficulty getting JUNG and Error Prone to work nicely together in my Gradle based Java project, and I wonder if someone has come across a problem like this before and can help me find a solution.

I've posted this problem already on the GitHub issue trackers for [JUNG](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/issues/66) and [Error Prone](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/466), but no one seems to know what's the cause of it, which is why I'm posting it here.

> When I try to run `gradle run` with the following `build.gradle`
>
> ```
> plugins {
>   id 'application'
>   id 'java'
>   id 'net.ltgt.errorprone' version '0.0.8'
> }
>
> group 'org.jbduncan'
> version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
>
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8
>
> mainClassName = 'org.jbduncan.helloworld.HelloWorld'
>
> repositories {
>   jcenter()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   compile 'net.sf.jung:jung-graph-impl:2.1.1'
>   errorprone 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.0.11'
> }
>
> tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
>   options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
>   options.compilerArgs = [
>     '-Xlint:all',
>     '-Werror'
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> and this class
>
> ```
> package org.jbduncan.helloworld;
>
> public final class HelloWorld {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>     System.out.println("Hello, world!");
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> it emits the following message.
>
> ```
> :compileJava                                                                     
> warning: [path] bad path element "C:\Users\Jonathan\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.jung\jung-graph-impl\2.1.1\8293acb2ab4c00a3939cb99a8751e5d38a4299dc\jung-api-2.1.1.jar": no such file or directory
> warning: [path] bad path element "C:\Users\Jonathan\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.jung\jung-graph-impl\2.1.1\8293acb2ab4c00a3939cb99a8751e5d38a4299dc\guava-19.0.jar": no such file or directory
> warning: [path] bad path element "C:\Users\Jonathan\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.jung\jung-api\2.1.1\e47ee4efdfacce12f0af620747d9d0e44bf2eaa4\guava-19.0.jar": no such file or directory
> error: warnings found and -Werror specified
> 1 error                     
> 3 warnings
> :compileJava FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> > Compilation failed with exit code 1; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 5.488 secs
> ```
>
> When I investigate the contents of my Gradle cache, I can see that, indeed, the jar files mentioned above simply don't exist.
>
> When I look into `C:\Users\Jonathan\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.jung\jung-graph-impl\2.1.1\8293acb2ab4c00a3939cb99a8751e5d38a4299dc\jung-graph-impl-2.1.1.jar`, the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` contains this text.
>
> ```
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
> Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
> Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
> Built-By: jrtom
> Build-Jdk: 1.8.0-google-v7
> Class-Path: jung-api-2.1.1.jar guava-19.0.jar
> ```
>
> I get the same problem with JUNG versions 2.1 and 2.0, and no other library with dependencies I've tried seems to have this problem.
>
> However the problem goes away when I exclude from `build.gradle` the lines `id 'net.ltgt.errorprone' version '0.0.8'` and `errorprone 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.0.11'`, so it's not clear to me if this is a problem with JUNG or if it's [gradle-errorprone-plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin) or Error Prone related.

I think it's worth noting that since I posted the question above on the JUNG issue tracker, I upgraded my project's version of Error Prone from 2.0.11 to 2.0.13, but unfortunately that didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: I've also posted my question on the Gradle forums [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/unable-to-use-xlint-all-in-a-gradle-project-with-gradle-errorprone-plugin-and-jung-library/20038), so if I manage to get an answer there, I'll close this question with the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved as of [this bug fix to JUNG](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/pull/75).